# Using Imageresizer diskcache with virtualfolder

Tags: imageresizer

Im trying to combine the ImageResizer plugins DiskCache and Virtualfolder, becouse I want to save the images to a network path. I have added both plugins in my webconfig:

```
 <resizer>
    <plugins>
      <add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
      <add name="DiskCache" />
      <add name="PrettyGifs" />
      <add name="SimpleFilters" />
      <add name="VirtualFolder" virtualPath="~/" physicalPath="D:\temp\diskcache" vpp="false"/>
    </plugins>
    <diskCache dir="~/" autoClean="false" hashModifiedDate="true" enabled="true"
             subfolders="32" cacheAccessTimeout="15000" />
  </resizer>
```

But I dont understand how I should map the VirtualFolder diskcache dir, to save to the physical path.

Could someone give an example how to save images with diskcash to a network path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use an IIS virtual folder, not an ImageResizer virtual folder. And it can't be the root of the site, it needs to be a subdirectory.

Comment: So I cant use the VirtualFolder plugin to "simulate" an IIS Virtual folder, even if I fix the path to be a subdirectory, like this:
<add name="VirtualFolder" virtualPath="~/imagecash" physicalPath="D:\temp" vpp="false"/>
....
   <diskCache dir="~/diskcache" autoClean="false" hashModifiedDate="true" enabled="true"
             subfolders="32" cacheAccessTimeout="15000" />

Comment: No, it must be an IIS virtual folder.

Comment: Ah, to bad! Thought it would work becouse it was in the same library as disk cache.
Tried to set up a virtual directory on my local machine and it worked. Looks like the only way, thanks for the help!

Comment: No, the ImageResizer VirtualFolder (as documented) is only for prototype and development use, and cannot be used with DiskCache.